# Mouse gone and unresponsive keyboard after installing Guest Additions

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to set up an Ubuntu VM in my Windows machine using Oracle VirtualBox. It worked fine until I installed the Guest Additions that enable the VM full-screen mode.

When I start up the VM now the mouse no longer works in the Ubuntu VM (it doesn't even show up) and using the keyboard does nothing either (password prompt).

I have tried [these solutions](https://superuser.com/questions/694155/mouse-disappear-in-virtualbox) and none worked.

Comment: The same thing happened to me, after installing (apparently) the wrong version of plugins for the Guest Additions, via the terminal.